# Can I use a USB hub to connect extra flash drives?

Tags: xbox-360

I have been trying to us a USB hub to allow me to use multiple flash drives on my Xbox 360.

I have read that you can only use up to 2 devices for up to 32gb of memory but that only confuses me more:  2 of my 6 ports seem to acknowledge any memory devices, even if there's only 1 plugged in.

I was under the impression that you can use 2 devices for up to 32gb, yet, I'm currently, somehow, using 32gb of a 2TB hard drive in addition to a 16gb flash drive.

How/why is it letting me go over 32GB?

I've  read that you can use a USB hub for the 360, but, I can't get this to work. It only acknowledges 1 of the flash drives plugged into the multi-tap.

The reports I've seen are talking about using multiple memory sticks.  Why am I having a different experience?

-I have the latest Xbox model, the "slim" I believe it's called.

Comment: Might help if you specify the type of Xbox 360 you have.

Comment: @Twon-ha - What type of Xbox 360 shouldn't matter they are all created equal in this case. I don't see the problem Xbox 360 will let the user use 2 32GB devices.  The current setup sees 32GB and 16Gb well within that configuration.

Answer (score 2):

One of the only issues you may run into with this is that a USB device may need more power than what is available on the USB bus. In that case, simply use a powered USB hub. There is also the possibility that the amount of devices that may be attached is limited in some way by the hardware manufacturer, but in this case that is very doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed, I personally use flash drives, I have 2 16GB flash drives plugged into mine, I also had an adapter to attach 3 more, although I only used it twice, it did work.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, and the best thing is, that not only the drives work with a hub, you may even connect 4 controllers via cable then. I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can after the last dashboard update you can now use two(2) 32gb flash drives or two 16gb flash drives and 32gb of an external HDD.. Game on.. :-)